# AngularJS : Browser back does not work with UI-Router with $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a page with TABs with Sub-Menu, as shown in link below using ui-router to achieve this.

See the code snippet:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OoywuaKkYLtYcVG659Mw?p=preview

Final UI will look like following where dashboard is parent for Order & Report.

```
Home   Dashboard
        Order              Report 
          Step 1             Step 1 
          Step 2             Step 2
```

On dashboard page I have a logic to navigate to child states using function mentioned below.

```
$scope.navigateToStep = function(chapter, step){
  console.log('navigateToStep is loaded');

        switch(chapter) {
          case 1: {
            switch(step) {
              case 1: {
                //do some extra logic and navigate to Step 1.
                $state.go('dashboard.order.step1',{},{reload:true});         
                break;
              }
              case 2: { $state.go('dashboard.order.step2',{}, reload:true}); break;}
              default: console.log("correct step not provided");
            }
            break;
          }
          case 2: {
            switch(step) {
              case 1: { $state.go('dashboard.report.step1',{},{reload:true}); break;}
              case 2: { $state.go('dashboard.report.step2',{},{reload:true}); break;}
              default: console.log("correct step not provided");
            }
            break;
          }
         default:{}
        }
      }
});
```

Navigation works fine when I click on Step 1 or Step 2 however browser history back button does not behave way it should.

For example: If suppose,

- Navigate to dashboard/order/step1,
- Navigate to dashboard/order/step2
- **Click history back button, it should ideally go back to dashboard/order/step1, however it does not.**
- **Additionally I can URL resets to parent state.**

*There is an similar issue on ui-router posted on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1583,  but it does not provide solution.*

Appreciate your valuable suggestions on this.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, (probably not a) stupid question, but since you don't specify... where does it go when you click the back button?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are using the 'navigateToStep' method instead of just ui-sref="..." in your dashboard.html markup?

Comment: @Sunil : It does not go anywhere in first back button click .but url changes  from /#/dashboard/order/step1 to /#/dashboard/

Comment: @O4ohel : I use navigateToStep because I have to process some logic in my controller before navigation to next page. It does work fine if I use uisref but I m confused why it does not with  $state.go

Comment: You mentioned the back button works properly when you use `ui-sref` instead of `$state.go()`. One difference is that you are reloading the states when you do $state.go ... I'm not sure I understand that. Typically, you only want to reload the state to reload the current state, you shouldn't need it when going to a new state.  Does removing the reload have any effect?

Comment: @Maverick09 : I would recommend using ui-router's [onEnter/onExit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks) callbacks then.

Comment: @Sunil : I have added reloadind state was only a attempt to fix this issue but this issue is there with or without reload the current state

Comment: @O4ohel : Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: @O4hel : I looked at it, It will require me to put my logic within routes, which I want to avoid. Is there any reason you would think above implementation is not working. ?

Comment: @Any other suggestions why browser back would not work with $state.go()? Thanks